# What does "persay"/"per say" mean?

Tags: meaning

I heard: "It shouldn't break any of your site **persay**."

I searched for it but cannot find it, not even in a dictionary.

What does *persay* or *per say* mean?

Comment: "Too localised".

Comment: Voting to close. It is *per se*, not persay.

Comment: I once interviewed with Per Se Technologies (www.per-se.com; now forwards to McKesson). The HR representative from Per Se was greatly annoyed when I corrected her; she pronounced it exactly as the proper name, "Percy. "

Comment: I've encountered apparent native speakers writing it down is "per say", even though I don't think it's correct *per se*.

Comment: The reason why the user could not find ***per se*** was because he was looking under ***persay***, now this well-meaning edit has made nonsense of the whole thing.

Comment: The comment above  explains why I rolled back the edit.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You heard:

> It shouldn't break any of your site *per se*.

*per se* is a Latin phrase often used in English.  It means "in itself".  So the person who said *per se* could have meant: "It shouldn't break the site, but it could break other things that you care about." or perhaps "It shouldn't break the site, but it could cause problems that are similar to a broken site."

Try [wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/per%20se) for examples of usage.

Comment: So, in context, what was meant was that the thing itself wouldn't break any of your site, but it's possible that it did so indirectly, in conjunction with something else or that someone broke your site while added or using that thing, and so on. It itself didn't break your site, but they weren't necessarily completely unrelated.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It depends on the context!  What is "it"?  ANd what kind of "site" is it?  A website?  A construction site?  Jusfeel hasn't told us (yet).

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can explain what: "I don't think it broke" means without knowing what "it" is or in what way it might break.

Comment: Okay.  I'll do it for you, David.  :)